# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).documentForm is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am trying to use jquery - ui select widget but when i include this:

`<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>`

I get this error message. otherwise it work fine  but looks bad. Any help or suggestion please?

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(function() {

    jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator, {
        required: 'Полето е задолжително',
        email: 'Внесете валидна емаил адреса.',
        date: 'Внесете валиден датум.',
        number: 'Венсете валиден износ'
    });

    $("#documentForm").documentForm({
        title: 'Согласнот за користење на BranchOffer',
        buttonSendButtonID: 'buttonSendButtonID',
        OnSendHandler: function(formCollection) {
            $("#ctl00_DefaultContent_ctl00_hFormCollection").val(formCollection);
            $("#ctl00_DefaultContent_ctl00_lbEntryFormNext").click();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: As your error message say, documentForm is not a jQuery function

Comment: What is `documentForm`..?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to use a plugin without including it on the page. Include the plugin javascript on the page after including jquery and it should work